# Ruby regex for matching simpliest Ruby's regexes

Tags: ruby, regex, recursive-regex

I want to match regexes (at least the basic ones, not all their possible kinds... for now...) in a text of Ruby script.
It's something like a... `\/\^? oh my god... \$?\/[eimnosux]*`

Maybe I need recursive regex here.

Comment: I'm still skeptic about it. Even a simple string like "hello world" can be used as a regex pattern for example. Are you asking for some kind of heuristic?

Comment: @alpha-mouse, `\/\^? \$?\/[eimnosux]*` is a base example of what I want. I want to match regexes, placed in Ruby source-code in their simpliest form: `/....../`. Not `%r{}` or `Regex.new(str)`.

Comment: You'll need to actually parse Ruby for this. Think about this line of code: `x = foo/bar*str[/foo/,1].to_i` You cannot know if that first slash should start a regex or not without actually parsing Ruby code according to its grammar.

Comment: @Phrogz, I know it, and I'm parsing Ruby code. I'm trying to parse it all using regex, not iterative char-by-char reading algorithms. My another part of parser in your example sees, that regexp can't be just after `foo` and that `/` is a method.

Comment: @Nakilon I'm curious how your parser sees that. `foo / bar` is valid division and `foo /bar/` is valid method invocation passing the regex as a parameter.

Comment: @Phrogz, in case of `a /b/c` parser knows, that some identifier `c` can't be after regexp - it's syntaxic error. So it will parse this like two `./` methods. But in case `a /b/i` even I don't sure, is it specified, how to interpretate this, so it's smth like `a+++b++` in C++ and can be parsed as I want ) By the way, I suppose, that placing regexps in `()` is a good practice. Let think that input to parser I'm writing surely doesn't have regexes without `()` around of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented above, you'll need to parse Ruby to differentiate division slashes and regex delimiters. But for the simplest, SIMPLEST case without worrying about this, how about:

```
regex_match = %r{/(?:[^/\\]|\\.)+/[mgixo]*}
```

That is "A forward slash, followed by one or more things that either aren't a forward slash or a backslash, or are a backslash followed by something else, finally followed by a slash, and possibly some regex flags."

Comment: Looks nice. Need testing. I thought it will need recursion with named groups.