# ruby input processing

Tags: ruby

I have to read some user input in ruby. The input mostly consists of regex, so I was thinking of splitting it by spaces to get the separate expressions. The issue is, however, that something like `'/[0-9] [0-9]/'` will be split in two, which I don't want.

The workaround I thought of was to just read the string until an expression's beginning and end are found, and then cut it there to get a substring, and repeat. Not sure if this is the best way to do it though. Any other ideas?

Sample input:

`/- / /[a-z][0-9]/ bbb`

Comment: The usual way to do this is to require the user to wrap arguments in quotation marks if they contain spaces.

Comment: can you tell us what's the main idea of reading regexs from users input?

Comment: It's actually a homework assignment. I'm trying to figure out the smartest way to do it.

Comment: You say input "mostly" consists of regex... what else?

Comment: @larsenal that and non regex, I updated the sample

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby regex for matching simpliest Ruby's regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206838/ruby-regex-for-matching-simpliest-rubys-regexes)

Comment: _"It's actually a homework assignment. I'm trying to figure out the smartest way to do it."_ And you solution is: "post it on StackOverflow", right :)? (Just sayin'.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you could use the following regex in Ruby with `scan`:

```
/\/[^\/]*\/|\S+/
```

Here is a sample irb session:

```
irb(main):001:0> s = '/- / /[a-z][0-9]/ bbb'
=> "/- / /[a-z][0-9]/ bbb"
irb(main):002:0> s.scan(/\/[^\/]*\/|\S+/)
=> ["/- /", "/[a-z][0-9]/", "bbb"]
```

I don't know if it will work with all your input data but it works with the example.

Now if the regexes can have backslashes inside of them and specifically `\/` then you have to use another regex:

```
/\/(?:\\.|[^\\\/])*\/|\S+/
```

Here is a sample irb session with the new regex:

```
irb(main):003:0> s = '/- \/ \/ / /[a-z][0-9]/ bbb'
=> "/- \\/ \\/ / /[a-z][0-9]/ bbb"
irb(main):004:0> s.scan(/\/(?:\\.|[^\\\/])*\/|\S+/)
=> ["/- \\/ \\/ /", "/[a-z][0-9]/", "bbb"]
```

Comment: I actually broke my program into 3-4 main cases and just handled those, but this looks like a solid general solution, thanks!